# Twitter summary card image is not always displayed

Tags: reactjs, api, twitter, next.js, twitter-oauth

So i have a website which is builded with NextJS and i'm using Next SEO plugin for filling the meta tags necessary for twitter and facebook info...
I have card type option set to summart_large_image

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

i can see that it's added to the website and it does work for some of the posts ... but something weird is happening , for example two of the tweets will have card with large image and then three of them would be just plain text with the link ...

I have a CMS in Silex where it's implemented automatic posting on twitter with twitter's API... and basicly i'm just posting a string with the link and some additional comment about it ... when i try do debugg with the twitter card validator it does work properly but not on my account ...

here's a screenshot for better explanation, the red ones are cards with large image and the blue ones have only text with link
[image]

All the posts have the same structure and equal size provided for the og:image tag.... all of them are equal basicly

Edit:
This is the twitter account in question for more clarity : https://twitter.com/someecards

Edit:
Now i even got a summary card with small image on a post which contains meta tag "summary_large_image" , and when i run the same link throught the link validator i'm getting the desired result

[image: From twitter timeline]

Link validator:
[image]

Comment: This is impossible to debug without seeing the links and the meta tag content for the non-working shares.

Comment: I assumed , this is the twitter account in question ... https://twitter.com/someecards

Comment: @AndyPiper i even added "&utm_source=twitter" at the end of the links to try and force twitter to treat the links as new and recrawl them... but still nothing ... 
If run the link throught the Twitter Card Validator it does refresh it after few times refreshing the site and runing throught the validator... is there a way i can do this automaticly after the links has been posted ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sometimes Twitter is not able to build the Card Preview (maybe a timeout when fetching the data or image) and, after that, the link is never accessed again, hence the preview is not rebuilt.

You can validate the preview with the [Twitter Card Validation](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) tool but it will probably work and show the correct link.

I have explained how the Card Preview works and limitation in a [blog post](https://medium.com/@beppe.catanese/tweesky-dont-miss-the-twitter-card-preview-19c95f3417d9), and created a tool to work around it.

In your case I would make sure the page is built before you post it onto Twitter, to make sure it is ready and served with minimum delay when the Twitter bot access it to generate the preview.

Comment: i believe that your tool won't help in my case , my website doesn't miss any meta tags needed for generating the preview card... and about the theory that the page is not ready , the posts are created and scheduled for posting in the future , so they are ready before are being posted... and Twitter Card Validation always display the right preview with large image which is not the case for the timeline